SASS throwing errors when using @use with mixins
I just started using SASS with Jekyll and I am encountering a strange issue when I started using @use. I have a mixin in another file, located in common/_theme-colors.scss:
$logo-color-0: rgb(78, 184, 148);
$logo-color-1: rgb(173, 195, 226);

@mixin template-text-gradient {
  color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
  background-image: linear-gradient($logo-color-0, $logo-color-1);
}

Then, I tried to do @include template-text-gradient in the main sass file after @use "common/theme-colors" as theme-colors:
@use "common/theme-colors" as theme-colors; 

// Header title
.site-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2em;
  
  // Gradient
  @include theme-colors.template-text-gradient();
}

I've done this by reading the official SASS documentation on @use and @mixins. However, when I try to compile the sass, I get this error:
(sass):14: Invalid CSS after "...de theme-colors": expected "}", was ".template-text-..." (Sass::SyntaxError)

It seems that SASS is expecting the @include theme-colors.template-text-gradient(); to end at
@include theme-colors;
It seems that it expects theme-colors is a mixin, not another file I am using. I'm not really sure why this is happening as I can't see any difference between the code I'm using and what is suggested in the documentation.
Additionally, the @include does work when I use @import instead of @use:
// Custom styles
@import "common/theme-colors"; 

// Header title
.site-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2em;
  
  // Gradient
  @include template-text-gradient();
}

This will compile with no errors and work as expected.
Why is this error thrown and why does it work only with the legacy @import?

What sass compiler do you use? Also, you don't need to write as theme-colors since this is already the name of your file.

@Arkellys I'm using Jekyll which is a static site generator written with Ruby. Its SASS compiler is Embedded Dart Sass, available as a Ruby library.

Alright, maybe a problem with your version of Jekyll? Are you on the latest?

seems the dot after theme-colors is tripping it up. perhaps that syntax is just not supported by that SASS library? does the official example copied verabtim work in that library? if in doubt, consult that library's documentation.

@mb21 Using dots to reference variables/mixins in other files is the only recommended standard to include mixins. In other languages as well, if you need a variable/function from a different library, you would also use a dot, so I don't think the issue is with it not being suppported.  I've taken a look at the library documentation already, with the link I provided in the OP, and the example copied verbatim does not work. So it's possible that the issue is with the installation of SASS.

@Arkellys I have Jekyll version 4.3.3, which is the latest.

seems similar to https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2138 ?

@mb21 Thx for the help but I think this issue is about someone trying to set a variable to a mixin, whereas I am setting a property of a class, so it isn't the same problem.

I think the issue is with how you are importing the mixins from other files.
// Current (not-working) code: 
@use "common/theme-colors" as theme-colors; <-- Your problem.

.site-title {
  @include theme-colors.template-text-gradient();
}

The error you're encountering is due to how @use works compared to @import. When you use @use, all mixins, functions, and variables from the imported module are namespaced.
This is actually a feature designed to prevent naming conflicts between different modules.
2 ways to fix it:
// 1) import everything as * so that @include can access it directly.
@use "common/theme-colors" as *;  <-- SOLUTION 1

.site-title {
  @include template-text-gradient();
}


// 2) if you want to keep the namespace, you would use it like this
// Alternatively you can use camelCase instead of hyphen-case

// Note: 'theme' or 'themeColors' will work. 'theme-colors' will not

@use "common/theme-colors" as theme; <-- SOLUTION 2

.site-title {
  @include theme.template-text-gradient();
}


Hello, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, when I do @use "common/theme-colors" as theme; I get the same error message. However, when I do @use "common/theme-colors" as * I get an error message saying template-text-gradient is an unidentified mixin. However, I am unsure why the mixin can be imported/identified in the first place, why is there not an error when i do @use, only when I include the mixin I attempted to load with @use? However, if the error is with the file not being able to be imported (which it may not be), why does @import work? Thank you for the help though.
